# Can't connect to localhost? - apache/ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I've installed apache on ubuntu using Amazon webservices and i can't seem to connect to localhost via my browser when i type in the IP address.

I have checked that the appropriate ports are opened, httpd is running, curl -R localhost returns me a html file from documentroot.

I have also added some VirtualHost directives

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName: testerproject.com
     DocumentRoot: /etc/apache2/document_root
 </VirtualHost>
```

and editted /etc/hosts file by adding

```
172.0.0.1 testerproject.com
```

But i am also unable to access the site with that hostname.

The only way i am able to access my server from a browser is by using the IPv4 public IP provided from AWS '54.69.177.170'.

How can i access localhost and the virtualhost that i made?

Comment: Have taken remote of that server machine? From which machine you are trying to access your server using localhost?

Comment: @AnilAgrawal What do you mean by 'have taken remote of that server machine'? I am trying to access it from the same computer that i've set up apache and aws on.

Comment: You can't access a server with localhost, that is hosted on different machine.

Comment: Your machine and the Amazon ec2 instance are not same machine. If still you want to access it using localhost, you need to setup request forwarding over ssl secured connection

Comment: @AnilAgrawal Ok i understand now. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

The `localhost` loopback address is not accessible from any other host by definition. It's only accessible from the local host. It doesn't route from the network interfaces.

You still can still access `localhost` from your browser by using SSH tunneling. This will forward connections on an external port and then send it to the localhost.

Here's an example:
From your host at home (where your broswer is)

```
 ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N -R *:0:localhost:3000 ec2-user@host.amazonaws.com
```

This will then give you a port you can connect with:

```
Allocated port 34070 for remote forward to localhost:3000
```

Now you access the AWS `localhost` from your browser to http://host.amazonaws.com:34070. (or whatever port is returned)

Comment: What about the virtualhost? after adding that virtual host directive i am still unable to access the server with the ServerName. All it returns me on chrome is "testerproject.com’s server DNS address could not be found." Should i change the IP for the site to the one provided by AWS on /etc/hosts? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to connect to localhost. It seems just connecting to the AWS host directly on the regular HTTP port would be simplest.

Comment: You shouldn't need to mess with the apache config. That's a whole other can of worms

Comment: Yeah what i'm trying to achieve is just to get my Virtual hosts up and running. Followed a couple of tutorials and none of them seem to be working for me. I've added directives, checked permissions, pointed my doc_root appropriately and checked the ports. However i still can't connect to the ServerName i've specified for my virtual host. Not sure what else to do so i tried to connect to localhost to attempt to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any amazon instance is just like a remote machine.

A machine from where you are trying to access that remote machine has its own identity.

You can check it by entering command ifconfig from both the machines (from your machine and amazon instance).

You can access any server on that remote machine through its public/private IP (based on how you are connected to that remote machine).

Comment: If your problem is solved you may accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: My question is only partially answered. Thank you for giving me a better understanding about local hosts.